# multiple substrings ctrl-r (reverse-i-search)

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there a way to reverse search a previous command which contains given (multiple) substrings?  In <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or alternatives?

Suppose I remember editing a file whose name contains abc, and I am looking for the previous command:

```
$ history | grep nano | grep -i abc
nano /some/folder/here/filename_abc.extension
```

Ideally, I would like to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>" then "nano" and "abc" to get the previous command.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate says no, not really https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665274/bash-select-a-previous-command-that-matches-a-pattern

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to use an alias/function like the one proposed in the link.